# Codeigniter Ajax on insert function with validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this form where i can insert data, on code igniter. it has validations, all i want to do is to make it ajax. how can I put ajax on it?

my codes,

controller

// CREATE /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public function create(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('PROVINCE','Province Name','trim|required|max_length[30]|callback_if_exist');

    if($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE){

        $this->add_view();
    }else{

        if($query = $this->Provinces_Model->insert()){
            redirect('Provinces/index');
        }else{
            $this->add_view();
        }

    }

}
```

/////////// Checking duplicates

```
public function if_exist(){

    $available = $this->Provinces_Model->check_if_exist(); //change

    if($available){
        return TRUE;
    }else{

        $this->form_validation->set_message('if_exist','{field} already exist!');
        return FALSE;

    }

}
```

models

/// call back

```
public function check_if_exist(){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE PROVINCE = ?";
    $data = array('PROVINCE' => $this->input->post('PROVINCE'));

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $data);

    if($query->num_rows() == 0){

        return TRUE;
    }else{

        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

/////  CREATE /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public function insert(){

    $input = array(
            'PROVINCE' => $this->input->post('PROVINCE')
            );
    $insert = $this->db->insert($this->table,$input);
    return $insert;
}
```

and finally the view

```
            <div class="box-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="PROVINCE" class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2">Province Name:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PROVINCE" name="PROVINCE" value = "<?= set_value("PROVINCE"); ?>">
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group has-error col-sm-offset-7">
                <label class="control-label" for="error"><?php echo form_error("PROVINCE"); ?></label>
              </div>
            </div>
```

notice that I have the error reporting so and `value = "<?= set_value("PROVINCE"); ?>"` for retaining the value i inserted if its values did not pass the validation.. now I want to make it ajax as a practice because the next part that I am going to do is after I submitted a form, it will go to another form.

Comment: Form validation will not work with Ajax. Use this instead
http://jqueryvalidation.org

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code like below:

Controller:

```
public function create(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('PROVINCE','Province Name','trim|required|max_length[30]|callback_if_exist');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

        echo 'ERR';
    }else{

        if($query = $this->Provinces_Model->insert()){
            redirect('Provinces/index');
        }else{
            $this->add_view();
        }

    }

}
```

And the view's Javascript part:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    $('#send').click(function(){ // you should add an id called "send" to your submit button
   var province = $('#province').val();

        $.ajax({ 
            type:'POST',
            url:'yourposturl', 
            data: province,
            success:function(response){
              if (response = 'ERR') {
                $("#response").html('Some error text');
                 }
                else { 
                $("#response").html('Some success text');   
                }
            }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Also please change `<label class="control-label" for="error">` part to `<label class="control-label" id="response" for="error">` if you want to use this method.

Comment: redirect('Provinces/index'); if i do this, will the whole page load?

Comment: delete that part, if insert is OK just send an echo e.g. "OK".

Comment: i want is to redirect it back to my data table